# What have I done wrong in this?

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here][1]```py
df['Runs'] = df['Runs'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[-1]=="*" else x)

```
It shows 'int' object is not subscriptable error in Python.

I am trying to delete the last character of the column entries and parallelly convert it into integer or float.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCIa.png
```

Comment: Can you post a portion of your dataframe?

Comment: Is the Runs column string or numeric ?

Comment: As commented above, this appears to be a problem with the data and not with your lambda function. This exception is thrown when it expects a tuple/list and get's an int, so one of your object's has an element that is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the actual code as I don't have the entries to work with, but the error is occurring as, to the best of my knowledge, you're using the integer type value in an array

[https://www.stechies.com/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable/#:~:text=This%20error%20occurs%20when%20you,that%20variable%20is%20an%20integer](https://www.stechies.com/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable/#:%7E:text=This%20error%20occurs%20when%20you,that%20variable%20is%20an%20integer).

Depending on what you're doing, you could treat the initial input as a string then convert it to integer for the output

Comment: Okay I will try. I ran this code twice which gave me this error. Because int/float values are non subscriptable.
Running it first time after loading the dataframe helped.